# How can I get intellisense for .net dll in VS Code or VS 2017 when referenced from Python using Python.Net

Tags: python, .net, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, python.net

I am trying to use one of our .net library dlls in a python script using python.net. While vs code recognises the python code, there is no intellisense or code help for the .net imports. Is this support available in VS 2017 or Pycharm (maybe RIDER). I have googled for a bit and there does not seem to be a clear answer anywhere.

Comment: Here is the current status: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/255